# Are chained commands always executed in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

While coding in node.js (which is asynchronous), can I rely on my chained commands to be executed in order?

```
var x=new MyObject();
x.start().doAThing().stop()
```

Will `start` run first, followed by `doAThing` and then `stop`?

Comment: Yes, they will always be executed in order.

Comment: Short Answer: **Yes**

Comment: The functions themselves will run in the expected order, however, the actions said functions take may not complete in the expected order.

Comment: @KevinB Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: start will execute, return, doAThing will execute, return, and then stop will execute and return. If any one of them perform an asynchronous action, the asynchronous action will complete some time later, after all three have executed and returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Technically, yes, but you might want to consider organizing the code differently if some functions in a chain are asynchronous.

---

For example, each method in a sequence `x.start().doAThing().stop()` is a method call and it requires some object to operate upon. In order to call to `doAThing()`, the JavaScript VM must first evaluate `x.start()`, then look up `doAThing` function and only then can it start executing `doAThing`'s body.

What will `doAThing` do can be completely different depending on the value of `x.start()`!

```
MyObject.prototype.start = function () {
  if (/* condition */) {
    return {
      doAThing: function () {
        return {
          stop: function () {
            console.log('path1');
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
  else {
    return {
      doAThing: function () {
        return {
          stop: function () {
            console.log('path2');
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
};
```

However, your function can start asynchronous task which might happen out-of-order.

```
MyObject.prototype.start = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // This will happen out-of-order, usually after `stop` returns!
    console.log('timed out');
  }, 0);

  return {
    doAThing: function () {
      return {
        stop: function () {
          console.log('stop');
        }
      };
    }
  };
};
```

See on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fujacidezi/edit?js,console). Output:

```
stop
timed out
```

If you have to chain asynchronous functions, you have rewrite the code using callbacks, promises, or generators. For example, with promises:

```
var start = function (obj) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      // This will happen in order.                                            
      console.log('timed out');
      resolve(obj);
    }, 0);
  });
};

var doAThing = function (obj) {
  return Promise.resolve(obj);
};

var stop = function (obj) {
  // Synchronous functions are fine, too.                                      
  console.log('stop');
};
```

This chain will execute these functions in order:

```
Promise.resolve(x)
  .then(start)
  .then(doAThing)
  .then(stop);
```

Output:

```
timed out
stop
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what those functions are doing. Unless you use a callback, commands are executed in order. However if the logic of your start() function requires an asynchronous call, then the result will be available only after the call is completed. Which means that subsequent doAThing() function cannot use the results of an async call inside your start() function.

Comment: A callback won't change the execution order.  It's the IO vs computations that will change execution order.

Comment: Yes. Generally, IO commands use callbacks to send the result back. But functions like Array.prototype.map() or Array.prototype.forEach() use callback synchronously. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the answer is always yes.  While `x.start()` with fire right away, if it performs an io operation, Node's runtime will then create a thread to perform that operation, hence asynchronous, start was still fired right away and `x.start().doAThing()` will fire upon `x.start()` returning.  However, asynch io can come back with a response after the function returns, so if it is asynchronus, `.doAThing()` won't Have a response. This is why asynch functions use callbacks/promises/ES7 asynch functions, and technically ES6 generators can be used too, which can access the io response.  As long as it is not an io operation, Nodejs is synchronus.

So

```
function start(){
    var a = 1 + 1;
    return {
        doAthing: function(){ return a;}
    };
}
```

Will be completely synchronus.